# How to create a new column that specifies which range of years a date belongs to (like academic year)?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

In some cases, a "year" doesn't necessarily cycle from January 1st. For example, academic year starts at the end of August in the US. Another example is the NBA season.

My question: given data containing a date column, I want to create another column that refers to which period it falls in. For example, consider that we are given the following `tib`:

```r
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tibble)

tib <- tibble(my_dates = as_date(c("1999-01-01", "2010-08-09", "2010-09-02", "1995-03-02")))
tib
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   my_dates  
#>   <date>    
#> 1 1999-01-01
#> 2 2010-08-09
#> 3 2010-09-02
#> 4 1995-03-02
```

and we want to mutate a column that refers to the academic year each date belongs to, provided that the academic year starts on August 31st:

```r
desired_output <- 
  tib %>%
  add_column(belongs_to_school_year = c("1998-1999", "2009-2010", "2010-2011", "1994-1995"))

desired_output
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   my_dates   belongs_to_school_year
#>   <date>     <chr>                 
#> 1 1999-01-01 1998-1999             
#> 2 2010-08-09 2009-2010             
#> 3 2010-09-02 2010-2011             
#> 4 1995-03-02 1994-1995
```

How can I create the column `belongs_to_school_year` using `mutate()`, based on `my_dates`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and `lubridate` for this:

```
desired_output <- tib %>%
  mutate(school_year = case_when(month(my_dates) <= 8 ~ paste(year(my_dates)-1, year(my_dates), sep = "-"),
                                 month(my_dates) > 8 ~ paste(year(my_dates), year(my_dates)+1, sep = "-")))
```

or:

```
desired_output <- tib %>%
  mutate(school_year = if_else(month(my_dates) <= 8, 
                               paste(year(my_dates)-1, year(my_dates), sep = "-"),
                               paste(year(my_dates), year(my_dates)+1, sep = "-")))
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you show how you would generalize this to any arbitrary date (e.g., March 5th)?

Comment: Instead of using `month(my_dates) <= 8` you can use `my_dates <= as.Date(paste0(year(my_dates), "-03-05")`. If you decide on the `case_when` just replace `<=` with `>` again in the second case just like before